# should i been using _id in ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Before I start my code works but should I be using the following as I have?

```
<td><button ng-click="changeDelete(change._id)">Delete</button></td>
```

The Controller

```
var deleteChanges = $resource('/api/changes/:change_id')

    $scope.changeDelete = function (change) {
        $scope.changes[change];
        deleteChanges.delete({change_id:change});
    $scope.changes.splice(change, 1);

    }
```

The reason I'm asking is because I been trying and failing without the ._id as my return string was

```
changes/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

When it should have been

```
changes/54fe15da2e36f81b44abb526
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this either way.  If you want to pass in the object instead of the property update this line:

```
deleteChanges.delete({change_id:change});
```

to

```
deleteChanges.delete({change_id:change._id});
```

Again, either way is fine.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct (I had just made the changes before seeing your reply nweg. This is what I changed:                              The Angular: <td><button ng-click="changeDelete(change)">Delete</button></td>                                                The controller: $scope.changeDelete = function (change) {
            deleteChanges.delete({change_id:change._id}, function (success) {
                $scope.changes.splice($scope.changes.indexOf(change), 1);
            });
        };

Comment: I appreciate it.  Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Interestingly I also needed to indexOf otherwise the list would delete the incorrect item in the foreground but the correct item in the background(db).

Comment: I wasn't sure what you were trying to do with those lines of code so I didn't comment on them.  But what you are saying sounds right.